# Prove that $\{f_1, f_2\}$ is a basis for V*

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V = $P_1(\Bbb R)$ and define $f_1, f_2 \in$ V* by

$f_1(p(x))$ = $\int_0^1 p(t)dt$

$f_2(p(x))$ = $\int_0^2 p(t)dt$

for all $p(x) \in V$.  Prove that $\{ f_1, f_2\}$ is a basis for V* and find a basis for V for which $\{ f_1, f_2\}$ is the dual basis.

For the second part I found that the basis for V that has $\{ f_1, f_2\}$ as the dual basis is $\{ b_1, b_2\}$ where

$b_1 = 2-2x$  and $b_2 = x-0.5$

I'm having trouble showing that $\{ f_1, f_2\}$ is a basis for V*, which simply amounts to showing that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent.

So I suppose

$af_1(p(x)) + bf_2(p(x)) = 0$

that is

a$\int_0^1 p(t)dt$ + b$\int_0^2 p(t)dt$ = 0

(a+b)$\int_0^1 p(t)dt$ + b$\int_1^2 p(t)dt$ = 0

I don't seem to be able to conclude that a and b are zero.  Is there another way to do this or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider $p(x) = 2x - 1$. What can you say about $b$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you should be supposing that $af_1+bf_2=0$, that is, $af_1(p)+bf_2(p)=0$ *for every* polynomial $p\in P_1(\mathbb R)$. If either of $a,b$ are nonzero, can you find a nonzero $p\in P_1$ for which your last expression fails?